# Time Domain Data for DTC storage in Autosar Diagnostic

Tags: embedded, system.diagnostics, autosar

Autosar Diagnostic is implemented by taking standards of UDS ( ISO 14229). 
As per that, once DTC is logged the snap shot data is stored as per UDS. Snap shot data is implemented via freeze frame data concept in Autosar Dem Module.

But I want to save some more information about DTC apart form snap shot data. I want to store data to be stored before 3 second and after 1 second of confirming DTC with sampling of 400 millisecond. So I need to store 10 samples of data every time when DTC gets locked.

I want to implement this time domain data in Autosar Diagnostic. Can I do that?, If yes, How?
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some more data about Autosar Diagnostic.

Answer (score 2):

We had a customer, that wanted to have almost the same, 15 FreezeFrames, 12 before the failure, one at the failure, and two after that, with a similar cyle. We used a ringbuffer updated cyclically. We used a callout from Dem (either DemCallbackEventStatusChanged() or DemCallbackDTCStatusChanged()), to stop the ringbuffer and count for two more. After they are logged, we stored them in an extra NvM Block. You might have several of these NvM blocks, and link that number to the DemEvent (FF Data?). E.g. the NvM Block could be a NVM_DATASET, so you could use an index. When reading out DTCs look for the assignment and read out the NvM DataSet index.

Otherwise, you might find a way with StorageConditions, disable them at first at first reporting and enabling after the freezeframes are complete?

I don't know though of a Dem feature to support this directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand where your problem is.
As you mentioned, snapshot data is stored together with the DTC. The content of the snapshot data you can define referencing DIDs. So, you need to define a new (internal) DID (in Dcm) where you provide your time domain data and add this DID in the Dem to the snapshot data (freeze frame).

Comment: I think the challenge for him is to also have it 1s after confirmation (guess he means maturation).
Storing a ring buffer of the past would, as you said, be easy.